# Complete list of fasteners for the Sintron Kossel

Tags: printer-building, diy-3d-printer, kossel

#### TL;DR

I need a complete list of fasteners (bolts, nuts and washers) for the *Sintron Kossel*.

---

Has anyone bought this kit, and knows the answer, or knows where this is documented?

A complete list would be great, but in particular, I need the dimensions (M2.5/3/4/5? and length) and quantity of the bolts (and nuts) which:

- fasten the PCB mounted mechanical switches to the PLA rectangular end stop spacers/holders, and;
- fasten the PCB mounted mechanical switches and the PLA rectangular end stop spacers/holders to the extruded 2020 aluminium.

I have:

- Searched the web, but to no avail;
- Read the [product page](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Sintron-3D-Printer-Kossel-Mini-Full-Set-w-Auto-level-for-RepRap-Rostock-Delta-/181845082062), which states only "screws and nuts provided";
- Contacted [Sintron](http://www.ebay.co.uk/usr/sintron_tech_usa), but not had an answer;
- Obtained the [Sintron build manual](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iifhhmistuwfja1/Kossel%20mini%20instrution%20by%20sintron%20technology_v2.pdf?dl=0) but there is no list contained therein, nor contains details about the fasteners relating to the endstops, and;
- Obtained the [Blomker manual](http://www.robotdigg.com/upload/pdf/2a823cc8a8dcff9da99cce92710cc745.pdf), from which the Sintron manual is copied, but that also has no list (as well as not being relevant with respect to the endstops).

**Note that I am only interested in the fasteners *specifically for the Sintron Kossel* and not the Kossel in general.** The Sintron uses the PCB mounted mechanical switches (with four holes), and not the simple barebones mechanical switches (with two holes), and uses 2020 aluminium<sup>1</sup>, not 1515 OpenBeam:

[image: Endstops and PCB mounted mechanical switches for the Sintron Kossel]

Why? Because I purchased only the 3D printed parts from Sintron, and I am sourcing the rest of the parts cheaply, either locally or from Chinese suppliers on eBay.

---

<sup>1</sup> In my particular case, there is an additional complication. The profile of the non-standard/non-"European" 2020 extrusion that I am using, does *not* take T-Nuts, only M5 hexagonal nuts (it is unbelievably difficult to find the standard 2020 extrusion in Bangkok). Combine that with the fact that the Sintron kit uses only M3 nuts and *not* M5 (I only discovered this *after* purchasing the printed parts kit (see the email from Sintron, in my answer below) - not through lack of research, but because there *is* no available list of fasteners), then I have the problem of finding a nut to use (see [Fat hexagonal M3 nuts, with outer diameter greater than 6 mm](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/fat-hexagonal-m3-nuts-with-outer-diameter-greater-than-6-mm)).

Here is a photo

[image: Four pieces of 2020 Aluminium extrusion]

Comment: The Sintron build manual clearly states what fastener is used for each location.  Every picture has the size and length on it.

Comment: For the endstops you're just going to have to measure what you have for parts and buy as needed.  I'm not even sure how they use all 4 holes as it looks like 2 of them may block the connection.

Comment: Also, many wire cutters/crimpers have bolt cutters built-in near the hinge that are more than capable of cutting M3 screws - http://a.co/dew90MR so you could just buy the longest length you can find that are fully threaded and cover everything below.

Comment: @tjb1 - Unfortunately, the SIntron build manual does not state it clearly for the endstops. Blocking the connection - yes, it is a pretty crappy printed kit, to be honest, FolgerTech is superior, although I only paid $20 for the PLA parts and $20 for the 2020 aluminium... Cutting bolts to length. with wire cutters, tends to damage the thread of bolt. A Dremel will do though, I suppose, but I would prefer, in order to keep costs to a minimum, to order the correct length of bolts, as the longer bolts cost more... Not by much I know, but I'm building these for people on extremely tight budgets.

Comment: @tjb1 - Hmmm, yes, upon reflection, the manual does clearly state that M3 bolts are used for the frame assembly. If only I had read the manual before buying the 2020 that only accepts M5 hex nuts, I would not be in such a pickle, I must admit.. :-) I might have to use this set of 2020 extrusions with another part set, that does use M5, and get a new set of lengths of "European"/Standard 2020 cut for use with the Sintron kit.

Comment: Have you tried to buy your extrusion from Misumi?  I'm not sure if they ship to the UK but they do have a European site and it is fairly cheap from them cut to whatever size you want.

Comment: @tjb1 - I am in Bangkok. I looked at Misumi about a month ago, but aluminium in Thailand is about 30-50% the price of US/Europe... although that would explain why you don't always get quite the right specification... :-)

Comment: You may want to simply make square "nuts" to suit your extrusion with flat stock, a saw, a drill, and an M3 tap. That's what I'd do, anyway, if I couldn't find ones to purchase.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Good idea, that would be a great answer to my question on SE.Engineering: [Fat hexagonal M3 nuts, with outer diameter greater than 6 mm](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/fat-hexagonal-m3-nuts-with-outer-diameter-greater-than-6-mm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining the guide ([Kossel mini instrution by sintron technology_v2](https://gr33nonline.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/kossel-mini-instrution-by-sintron-technology_v2.pdf)) and the printed parts kit, I came up with an 99.9% complete parts list. The lists relating to the effector and autoprobe mount maybe slightly incorrect:

```
##Parts List

###Listed by Printer part/section:

####Fasteners

#####BOTTOM VERTEX (QUANTITY = 3)

For each:
10 x M3 x 8 mm
10 x M3 nut (T-nut)

#####TOP VERTEX (QUANTITY = 3)

For each:
5 x M3 x 8 mm
5 x M3 nut (T-nut)

1 x M3 x 35 mm
1 x M3 nut
1 x M3 washer


#####IDLERS (QUANTITY = 3)

For each:
1x M3 x 25 mm
4x M3 Washers
1 x M3 Nut
2x F623ZZ

#####MOTORS (QUANTITY = 3)

For each:
2 x grub
4 x M3 x 8 mm
1 x 16T/20T GT2 pulley

#####EFFECTOR

6 x M3 nyloc nuts
6 x M3 x 25 mm

4 (5?) x M3 x 16 mm <<==, or
2 (3?) x M3 x 16 mm <<==
2 x M3 x 20 mm <<== For the auto probe, if mounting the autoprobe directly on to a collar, above the hotend, and not on to the flange on the Sintron PLA collar

4 (5?) x M3 nuts <<==

2 x M3 x 8 mm <<== fan mounted to Sintron PLA collar
2 x M3 nuts <<==

1 x PC4-M6

Note: Some additional bolts are required for the mounting of the hotend. It is unclear what these are. See link.

#####VERTICAL CARRIAGES (QUANTITY = 3)

For each:
2 x M3 x 20 mm

#####ROLLER CARRIAGES (QUANTITY = 3)

For each:
2 x M3 x 10 mm
1 x M3 x 25 mm
3 x M3 nuts
3 x M6 x 25 mm
3 x M6 nut    
2 x M6 washer (optional)

#####ENDSTOPS (QUANTITY = 3)

For each:
1 x M3 x 8 mm <<==
1 x M3 nut (T-nut)
3 x M3 x 8 mm <<==
3 x M3 nut

#####SPOOL

6 x 625-2RS Bearing (or 625zz)
5 x M5 x 20 mm
1 x M5 x 25 mm
6 x M5 nut
6 x M5 washer
(or 7 x M5 washer – there is a discrepancy between the kit (7) and the manual (6))
3 x M3 x 8 mm ?
3 x M3 nut (T-nut)

#####EXTRUDER

1 x M3 x 40 mm
1 x M3 x 8 mm
1 x M3 x ?? mm <<==
2 x M3 nut (T-nut)

1 x PC4-01

#####AUTOPROBE

Note: This is optional

2 x M2.5 x 12 mm
1 x M2.5 x 12 mm
2 x M3 x 8 mm <<==  If mounting the autoprobe on to the flange of the Sintron PLA collar (if mounting directly on to a collar, above the hotend, then these are not required, and 2 x M3 x 20 mm replace 2 x M3 x 16 mm on the effector)
2 x M3 nuts <<==  If mounting the autoprobe on to the flange of the Sintron PLA collar (if mounting directly on to a collar, above the hotend, then these are not required)

Safety Pin 2.5 mm
Spring 23.5mm

Terminal Block
1.5mm Allen key

Note: Some additional bolts are required for the mounting of the autoprobe, as well as the hotend. It is unclear what these are.

#####GLASS BED

3 x M3 x 8 mm ?
1 x M3 x 20 mm
4 x M3 nut (T-nut)

#####RAMPS

Note: This is optional, as mounting on the top will interfere with the spool

2 x M3 x 35 mm
2 x M3 nuts
2 x M3 nuts (T-nut)

###Total Parts:

####Fasteners

#####BOLTS

Size, Length, Quantity
M3, 25, (1×3)+(6)+(1×3) = 3+6+3 = 12
M3, 8, (10×3)+(5×3)+(4×3)+(4x3)+(3)+(1)+(2)+(3) = 30+15+12+12+3+1+2+3 = 78
M3, 16, 5
M3, 20, (2×3)+(1)+(2) = 6+1+2 = 9
M3, 10, (2×3) = 6
M3, 35, 3
M3, 40, 1
M6, 25, (3×3) = 9
M5, 20, 5
M5, 25, 1
M2.5, 12, 3

#####GRUB SCREWS

Size, Quantity
?, (2×3) = 6

#####NUTS

Size, Quantity
M5, 6
M6, (3×3) = 9
—
EITHER

M3, (10×3)+(5×3)+(1x3)+(1×3)+(5+2)+(3×3)+(1×3)+(3×3)+(3)+(2)+(2)+(4) = 30+15+3+7+9+3+9+3+2+2+4 = 90

OR

M3, (1×3) + (1×3) + (5+2) + (3×3) + (3×3) + (2) = 3+7+9+9+2 = 33
and
M3 T-slot nut, (10×3) + (5×3) + (1×3) + (3) + (2) + (4) = 30+15+3+3+2+4 = 57
—

#####NYLOC NUTS

Size, Quantity
M3, 6

#####WASHERS

Size, Quantity
M3, (1x3)+(4×3) = 15
M6, (2×3) = 6
M5, 6 (or 7)

####Bearings

Size, Quantity
F623zz, 6
625-2RS, 6
OR
625zz, 6

####Printed Parts

TBD

####Structural

3 x 2020 x  750/600 mm
9 x 2020 x 360/240 mm

####Electronics

1 x Arduino Mega 2560
1 x RAMPS 1.4
5 x Stepper drivers
3 x PCB mounted mechanical switch
3 x Stepper motors
1 x Extruder stepper

####Belts

3 x 16T/20T GT2 Pulley
GT2 belt (5 meters)

####Other Parts

Safety Pin 2.5 mm
Spring 23.5mm
Terminal Block
1.5mm Allen key
9 x Delrin wheels
9 x 696zz bearings

1 x PC4-M6
1 x PC4-01

###Uncertainties

The fasteners required for the following parts is, as yet, unclear

Effector/Hotend mount
Autoprobe mount
Additional Extruder holder screwpoint

###Assumptions

Hotbed frame mounts (assumed to be M3 x 8 mm)
Spool frame mounts (assumed to be M3 x 8 mm)
Endstops (four M3 x 8 mm are used, not just one)
```

See also [Kossel - Sintron parts list](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2017/06/01/kossel-sintron-parts-list/).

---

I have a *partial* answer from the suppliers:

> Hi
>
> Good Day !
>
> thanks for your contact.
>
> we use M3 bolts + T-nuts .
>
> i suppose the problem is , you don't have T-nuts , right ?
>
> T-nuts is used for 2020 extrusion.
>
> with warm regards.
>
> james

I replied for a clarification of the length required:

> Many thanks for the reply.
>
> I have two types of 2020 extrusion, with differing profiles: one that
>   takes T-Nuts, and; one that takes regular hexagonal M5 nuts.
>
> For the T-nut extrusion I have both M3 and M5 T-nuts.
>
> However, the second type of 2020 extrusion takes regular M5 nuts.
>   Regular M3 nuts will not stay in place, unless I can find some M3 nuts
>   with a larger outer diameter, greater than 7 mm.
>
> With respect to the M3 bolts, what are the lengths required? Are two
>   lengths used? One length to secure the endstop switch and holder to
>   the 2020 extrusion, and then another length to secure the remaining
>   three holes? Looking at the diagram in your build guide, it seems as
>   if only one bolt is used to secure the endstop switch and holder to
>   the frame, is that correct? Are any other bolts used to secure the PCB
>   mounted switch the the endstop holders.
>
> I thank you in advance.
>
> Best regards

I followed this up with a second email

> Hi again James,
>
> Following on from my previous reply.
>
> Firstly, I have found that flanged M3 nuts will work perfectly, in the
>   extrusion that will not accept T-Nuts.
>
> Secondly, what I really am looking for is a list of the lengths (and
>   dimensions) of the bolts used throughout the Sintron build. In
>   particular the endstop bolts. Rather than having to iteratively deduce
>   each bolt, a list of the bolts used would be very handy.
>
> I thank you again in advance for your kind consideration.
>
> Best regards,

I received a second reply from Sintron

> Hello Friend.
>
> for endstop . it's M3*8mm .
>
> i am collecting the list of them for you soon.
>
> thanks.
>
> james

---

Comment: As a friend of mine said "sounds like a lot of data; but no useful information".  I added some info on the t-nuts and screws to my answer above that may help.  [This is another solution](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2830-PC-METRIC-BOLT-NUT-WASHER-LOCK-WASHER-ASSORTMENT-KIT-W-36-HOLE-BIN/272649166675) that might work.

Comment: @markshancock - The particular 2020 aluminium extrusion, which I am using, will not accept regular T-Nuts, although I am not sure about the slim half T-Nuts. See [Fat hexagonal M3 nuts, with outer diameter greater than 6 mm](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/fat-hexagonal-m3-nuts-with-outer-diameter-greater-than-6-mm). Flanged hex M3 nuts seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @markshancock - I love the idea of 2830 pieces of fasteners... :-)  Unfortunately, upon further thought, flanged hex M3 nuts aren't a solution, after all. They would have no purchase on the sides of the slot and would spin hopelessly upon being tightened. Seems like I will have to get standard extrusion, that *will* accept T-nuts, and use the non-European extrusion for a different set of printed parts that use M5 nuts.

Comment: I am really surprised you are having so much challenge with the t-nuts fitting the extrusion.  The extrusion you have must have an non-standard profile.  If you buy more 2020 from eBay, I recommend you buy the t-nuts as part of the set.

Comment: Here is the [offering on eBay](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Sintron-2020-Openbeam-Aluminum-Extrusion-Kit-for-3D-Drucker-mini-Kossel-Rostock-/131521171318) where I got the profile.  I dislike linking eBay offerings since they are temporary.  I'm including it separately so I can deleted it later if the link goes dead.

Comment: @markshancock - I bought the 2020 in Bangkok, 6 meters for $20. See [Fat hexagonal M3 nuts, with outer diameter greater than 6 mm](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/fat-hexagonal-m3-nuts-with-outer-diameter-greater-than-6-mm) for a photo

Answer (score 3):

I found two lists for the Kossel mini (the documents you referenced are for a mini, so that is what I am assuming you got).  One as a [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s_ekMab3iavE6ohXIHZImjlCRGyXr9UWbBqC8XOGF_M/pub?output=html) and one as an [order sheet](http://www.tridprinting.com/BOM/Kossel-Mini/)

Both seem to list all the fasteners.

Here is a Sintron mini [carriage assembly](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/SINTRON-Kossel-Mini-Prime-Line-Roller-Carriage-Wheel-696ZZ-Bearing-linear-rail-MGN12/114769_32427917085.html) and it lists the hardware included

I found an ebay listing for the Sintron 2020 Rails.  The recommended screws are M3x20mm and here is the infor on the required t-nuts.[image]

Happy building.

Comment: Note: I don't have a Kossel; so, no guarantee the lists are complete.  Anyway, it is a kit; so the parts you need is a bit "flexible".  I built a Tronxy X3 kit and the parts supplied were mostly complete; but, several build steps called out parts that weren't in the kit.  I am glad I have a pretty good selection of screws and nuts in my shop.

Comment: Many many thanks, but unfortunately, they are not for the *Sintron* kossel. I have seen those links (see my (confused) blog [Kossel 3D Printer](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/kossel-3d-printer/). However, the Sintron Kossel, whilst having many common features with other Kossels, is a bit of a particular/peculiar beast. W.R.T. the  endstop holders, the Sintron uses the PCB mounted types (with four holes), and not the simple barebones mechanical switches (with two holes) that the TriDPrinting/Google docs uses. I'll update my question to be clearer.

Comment: @Greenonline   Well that is complicated.  I'll see what I can find and add it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the M3 t-nuts, could you use this [printed solution](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1573410).
You are just attaching a PCB; so, it you wouldn't need that much strength.

Another excuse to use your 3D printer. ;)

Comment: That is a good tip, but I need them, principally (along with other reasons), for attaching the extrusions to the vertices, so they need to be strong and in metal really...

Comment: But, why can't you use M5 for the other locations? (Note: Use of "But,"  is a homage to your [English Post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52239/why-do-people-incorrectly-begin-a-sentence-with-the-word-but)

Comment: **All of the holes** in the Sintron printed parts are M3. I considered reaming the holes to make them M5, but i don't want to lower the integrity of the parts, i.e. weaken them, nor have (slightly) misaligned screw holes, etc.

Comment: Did you buy them or print them your self?  I could see not wanting to redrill the holes in a printed part (as it you could cut into the infill); but, certainly they couldn't be that difficult to change the design to use M5.  I can't imagine the margins around the holes would be thin enough to compromise the part.  They can't be carrying that much load.

Comment: I ordered them from eBay. BTW, this is a good answer, but it answers the wrong question. That is to say that it doesn't provide a *Parts List for the Sintron*, which is what I am looking for *here*, but it does provide a solution to the big fat nut that I'm looking for on SE.Engineering. So, you should post this answer as an answer, or have it migrated, to my question on SE.Engineering: [Fat hexagonal M3 nuts, with outer diameter greater than 6 mm](Fat hexagonal M3 nuts, with outer diameter greater than 6 mm)

Comment: @Greenonline, I will add the comment to you engineering post; but, IMHO, it is providing you with a different option for one of the parts to use (so, an alternate parts list).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've just realised that this, as it stands, won't work, in my particular case (with the strangely profiled 2020), as it won't accept T-nuts, real, printed, or otherwise. However, I could use the same idea/principle to print some *pseudo* T-nuts that *would* fit the profile.

Comment: Best to make it your own anyway.  Maybe customize it to you hole pattern.  That is one of the benefits I love about 3D printing, you can make what you want rather than having to use with they make.

Comment: Another option would be to purchase some 4mm x 5mm [bar stock](https://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-aluminum-sheets) and tap your own holes.  All you would need is a [drill press](https://www.amazon.com/WEN-4208-8-Inch-Speed-Drill/dp/B00HQONFVE) and an [M3 Tap](https://www.amazon.com/Forsun-T-Handle-Ratchet-Wrench-Machine/dp/B01FTFX40S).  That would be as strong or stronger than someone else's t-nut.

Comment: Now *that* would be a great answer to [Fat hexagonal M3 nuts, with outer diameter greater than 6 mm](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/fat-hexagonal-m3-nuts-with-outer-diameter-greater-than-6-mm)